# Installing hashLib gives SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, pycharm, hashlib

I needed a simple hash function for passwords and thought I could use `hashlib`. PyCharm suggested to install it by running `pip install hashLib`.

But now PyCharm is complaining about a syntax error in the library:

```
Collecting hashLib
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/bb/9003d081345e9f0451884146e9ea2cff6e4cc4deac9ffd4a9ee98b318a49/hashlib-20081119.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/6_/8g1vyy5n1t1859x2d30ssk480000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/hashLib/setup.py", line 68
    print "unknown OS, please update setup.py"
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("unknown OS, please update setup.py")?

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6_/8g1vyy5n1t1859x2d30ssk480000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/hashLib/
```

It suggests that it may be a problem related to the Python version I am using (I tried with Python 2.7 and Python 3.8, but none of them worked).

> Make sure that you use a version of Python supported by this package.
>   Currently you are using Python 3.8.

Comment: How did you try to install it?

Comment: by adding it in the project interpreter and installing the package hashlib

Comment: You are not happy with the `hashlib` from the standard library?

Comment: "This is a stand alone packaging of the hashlib library included with Python 2.5 so that it can be used on older versions of Python (tested on 2.3 and 2.4)."

Comment: yeah... I see but it's PyCharm suggesting me this solution (to install hashlib)

Answer (score 19):

[`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) is in the standard library now.  That means you don't need to install it, it's there already with your Python installation.

The one you tried to install from PyPI is for *very* old versions of Python (<= 2.4).

Comment: but when I am trying to import it I got the error and it suggests me: "pip install hashLib" . So I do it in the terminal, and still it doesn't work. It complains about the parenthesis misspelling.

Comment: I think this is just PyCharm being dumb. Change the import to `hashlib` not `hashLib`.

Comment: Okay, now I got another type of error: "TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable"

Comment: Looks like hashLib problem is solved isn't it? As for frozenset problem, that would be a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Comment: no, no... actually I am getting the same error. I got the frozenset problem once I tried to download hashlib from the terminal. But now I am getting the misspelling error all the time